# Configure Apache web server to perform SSL authentication

Tags: linux, apache, security, ssl, xampp

I'm trying to perform SSL authentication in apache web server, using XAMPP in Linux. After I configure httpd.conf like this, Apache server is failing to start. Can some one help me to fix this ? What is wrong with my configuration ?

```
Alias /bitnami/ "/opt/lampp/apache2/htdocs/"
Alias /bitnami "/opt/lampp/apache2/htdocs"

<Directory "/opt/lampp/apache2/htdocs">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

Listen 443

<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:443>
    DocumentRoot "/opt/lampp/htdocs"
    ServerName localhost.localdomain
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile "/home/lahiru/Desktop/ucsc/security/ssl/server.cer"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "/home/lahiru/Desktop/ucsc/security/ssl/server.key"
    SSLVerifyClient require
    SSLVerifyDepth 10
    SSLCACertificateFile "/home/lahiru/Desktop/ucsc/security/ssl/ca.cer"
</VirtualHost>
```

And the Apache error log says,

```
(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:443
[Sun Jun 21 07:42:47.000754 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 1863] AH01909: localhost.localdomain:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Sun Jun 21 07:42:47.001082 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 1863] AH01906: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
[Sun Jun 21 07:42:47.001101 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 1863] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Sun Jun 21 07:42:47.001183 2015] [suexec:notice] [pid 1863] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /opt/lampp/bin/suexec)
```

Comment: If it's failing to start, presumably it is logging some errors that might help identify the problem. Is there anything in your Apache error log?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bitnami developer here,

In XAMPP the SSL configuration is located at `/opt/lampp/etc/extras/httpd-ssl.conf` file, where there is a default VirtualHost already configured in port 443, and you are trying to bind again the same port.

Please, try to modify this file instead. You can check if there is any other process using port 443 running command `sudo netstat -vnpa | grep 443`

What do you mean with "Apache server is failing to start"? Using the `/opt/lampp/ctlscript.sh` script to restart Apache server didn't produce any error message on my side but the `error_log` told me the same that you mentioned.

Regards,

Gonzalo